# python issue with regex and finditer, doesn't seem to match like it should

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use finditer / regex. I've got input that looks like it should be treated the same by the regex. In one case it matches, and in the other it doesn't. Please help me figure out why the qarg=foo is not being matched, but the qarg=bar is matched

here's the code:

```
    import re

def doit(line):
    re_args = re.compile('''\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=(?P<quote>['"]?)([^(?P=quote)]+)(?P=quote)(?=\s|$)''')

    print()
    for match in re_args.finditer(line):
        print(match.group(0))

doit(""" qarg=foo q=sw qarg='-B final'""")
doit(""" qarg=bar q=sw qarg='-B final'""")
```

===== here's the output ===

```
q=sw
qarg='-B final'

qarg=bar
q=sw
qarg='-B final'
```

notice that qarg=bar is being printed, but the qargs=foo in the first case isn't. What am I missing? I'm using 3.6.1 of python

Comment: Haven't posted this as an answer since I'm not sure how you can get around it, but looking on Regex101 the problem is in Capture Group 3: `([^(?P=quote)]+)` is being interpreted as "match any letters not in the literal set of characters "P","=","q", etc. Since "Foo" has an "o", it doesn't match. Link [here](https://regex101.com/), make sure you change it to Python (it also expects the double quote in group 2 to be escaped with a backslash). Edit: Looks like Wiktor beat me to it.

Comment: Well, `(?:(?!(?P=quote)).)+` won't work as when there is no `'` or `"`, the `(?!)` will fail any match.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you dont want the quote char in the capturing group? May be easier to strip the quote char after the regex as a post process than to do what you want with the regex

Comment: the logic was suppose to be that if there's a quote there match until the next quote. if there's no quote match until the next space. looking at it again, I think you're right something is wrong when there's no quotes. funny how it seems to work sometimes.

Comment: may have found something. if i replace the ([^(?P=quote)]+) with (.*?) it works. I was trying to match things that weren't the quote. I think it had problems when there wasn't a quote.

Comment: Are you sure [`\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=(['"]?)(.*?)\2(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/vGcyYC/1) is not enough? If not, use something like [`\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=(?:(['"])(.*?)\2|\S+)(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/vGcyYC/2). See [**this Python demo**](https://ideone.com/67QUBs).

Comment: that's close, but I need to handle the optional quotes. and I'm pretty sure the ?: won't work because I need to remember which quote I matched. don't think you can use a back reference to that if you use ?:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix was to use replace the ([^(?P=quote)]+) with (.*?)

If I used ([^(?P=quote)]+) it was empty when there wasn't a quote and the whole regex would be messed up at that point.